# How to automate log-off after process ends?

Tags: windows-10, shell, process, code, logout

My process is Playnite.DesktopApp.exe. I have set it up as my custom shell, so upon logging into my guest account in windows 10, this is the only process that boots up, nothing else.

After the process ends, I want to be logged out of the account automatically.

How do I do this?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Playnite has support for extensions as Powershell scripts. I would code a powershell extension that would replace the close functionality with a log off command, or something similar. Alternatively, add a custom game and make it just log off upon executing that game.

Comment: The alternative is going to be creating a custom launcher that launches playnite and as 2nd step log off. This can be a batch script compiled into an .exe or a program written in a programming language such as Visual Basic .net

Comment: @LPChip What if I'm looking to do this generally speaking, not in the context of Playnite.exe

Comment: Depends on what situation you are doing. best option is always to let the shell manage log off

Comment: @LPChip can you please write me the shell script that I could install as the extension for playnite?